# Center figure image and caption in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, figure

I have a figure containing an image and caption as shown below:

```
<figure class="figure">
  <img src="../img/atmpressure.svg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="pressue plot">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Plot of pressure at different altitudes.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[image: figure]

I am using Bootstrap 4 to style the web page. Using the `text-center` class for the caption, I'm able to center the caption text. I would also like to center the image in the figure. The `mx-auto` and `text-center` classes do not work when the image is within a figure (see example below).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- MathJax used to display equations -->
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}, CommonHTML: {scale: 130} });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <p>Elit ratione dolorum velit nesciunt aliquid Vitae culpa exercitationem ex animi quis praesentium Fuga sapiente dignissimos deserunt quia officiis nihil. Vero dignissimos excepturi iste ut fugiat! Nostrum quibusdam labore molestiae.</p>

        <figure class="figure text-center">
          <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" class="figure-img img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="pressue plot">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Plot of pressure at different altitudes.</figcaption>
        </figure>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I horizontally center the entire figure in the column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is two fold. Your original issue was that you only had `.text-center` on the `figcaption`. To center the `img` and `figcaption` in the `figure`, move `.text-center` to `figure` instead and that will center the inline `img` and text in the `figcaption` horizontally.

Then when you said that didn't work and included the context of the rest of the page, turns out you're wanting the `figure` to be centered relative to the content around it, too. `figure` has class `.figure`, which adds `display: inline-block;` so it will be left aligned in the `.col` by default. The easiest way to center the contents of the `figure` relative to the content outside of the `figure` is to either remove the `.figure` class so the element can be it's native `display: block` and `.text-center` will center it's contents, or you can add the class `.d-block` to the `figure` if you want to retain the `.figure` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Elit ratione dolorum velit nesciunt aliquid Vitae culpa exercitationem ex animi quis praesentium Fuga sapiente dignissimos deserunt quia officiis nihil. Vero dignissimos excepturi iste ut fugiat! Nostrum quibusdam labore molestiae.</p>
        <figure class="text-center">
          <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="pressue plot">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption">Plot of pressure at different altitudes.</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but they do not work. The caption is centered but the image is left aligned.

Comment: is this on your personal site/project? are they centered for you in my answer?

Comment: It's your responsibility to reproduce the problem in your post, and we fix the code in your post. I can't help you if you just say it doesn't work on your personal site. You likely have CSS overwriting it or something else wrong, could be a million things.

Comment: I edited my question with an example that illustrates the problem. When you run the code snippet, you can see that the figure remains left aligned within the column in relation to the paragraph of text.

Comment: what if you add `.d-block` to the `figure`?

Comment: And the image and caption are centered in the figure. It's the figure itself that isn't centered. I'm assuming you know that by now, but this is a lot different than your original question. Your original question was just about the image and caption within the figure.

Comment: The problem is with bootstrap. If I remove the `figure` and `figure-caption` classes and just use `text-center` on the html figure tag then everything works.

Comment: @wigging right, adding `.d-block` to the existing `figure` classes should do the same thing. Will that not work? If not, why? (assuming you still want help)

Comment: Yes, adding `text-center d-block` to the figure tag works if the `figure` and `figure-caption` classes are kept. Either approach (see my previous comment) works fine.

Comment: @wigging so you're good? or do you still need help? do you want me to edit the answer to include all the new context?

Comment: Had a similar problem and also solved it using text-center. Really strange that you can't do something like `figure text-center`!

Answer (score 1):

Try `w-100 text-center` class in figure tag.

Your code should look like this:

```
<figure class="figure w-100 text-center">   <!-- add 'w-100 text-center' class here -->
  <img src="../img/atmpressure.svg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="pressue plot">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Plot of pressure at different altitudes.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the image centering for me when one of the images are too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the "figure" class:

```
.figure {display: table;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;}

.figure-caption {display: table-caption;caption-side: bottom;text-align: center;}
```